# Do Exist or Are Exist?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am unable to determined word Exist is Adjective or Verb. Which one in the below sentence is correct to say ? Why ?

1) Yes, aliens do exist.

Or

2) Yes, aliens are exist.

Comment: Did you look up *exist* in the dictionary?  What part of speech does it say it is?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [*to be verb.*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exist)

> Yes, aliens *do* exist.

'Aliens exist' is correct. However, *do* is used to emphasize the existence.

Using *are* will be incorrect in that sentence. *Something* are *something* means they *are* that.

> They are dogs - they are dogs!
>
> Aliens *are* aliens - but they do not *exist!*

Comment: We could say, "Aliens are existing" – although it would be an awkward thing to say.